# Add python to Ida Pro 7.3

Tags: ida, idapython

I have Ida Pro 7.3 but at the bottom of windows, I see that I can run only the IDC script.

- How can I add Python to Ida ?
- Can I run Python script via IDA ?

Comment: I believe that you can only use Python 2.7 - not Python 3.X - with Ida 7.3

Comment: @fpmurphy . I can't  use even python 2.7.

Comment: @yfr24493AzzrggAcom Make sure you have installed the correct version (32/64 bit) depending on the Ida executable you use.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, the setup should register it for you (and even bundle the Python 3 setup). If it didn't you can point it to the appropriate python3.dll by using the `Python3TargetDLL` (REG_SZ) value at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Hex-Rays\IDA`.

So for a current Python 3.10.x you could set it to the value `C:\Program Files\Python310\python3.dll`. After a restart IDA should pick up on it.

You didn't specify the OS you run on, so I am assuming Windows.

Answer (score 0):

for me, i just add Python path into system environment path. Install Python2 and Python3 if you don't sure which Python should be :p

Comment: I have python in PATH but that not help....